# why does my scanner(system.in) run twice

Tags: java, if-statement

I am new to java, been self teaching for the last week. I cannot find the reason why the if else statement runs twice. here is the whole code, I know is simple but still trying to learn.

```
package tickets;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class tickets {
public static void main(String[] args) {
//program designed to ask how many visitors
//are in a party of people and work out
//the total cost of the entry tickets.
    double adult = 12.50;
    double consession = 9.90;
    double child = 6.25;
    double percentage = 0.80;

System.out.println("please enter the amount of adults");
Scanner adult1 = new Scanner (System.in);

//adding code that would give a percentage discount for 
//4 adults or more
{   
if ( adult1.nextInt() >= 4
{
double adult2 =( adult1.nextInt() * percentage);
            }else {
double adult2 = (adult * adult1.nextInt());



System.out.println("please enter the amount of consessions");       
    Scanner consession1 = new Scanner (System.in);
            double consession2 = (consession *consession1.nextInt());

    System.out.println("please enter the amount of children");
    Scanner child1 = new Scanner (System.in);
            double child2 = (child * child1.nextInt()); 

    System.out.println( "total"+" " + (adult2 +consession2 + child2) ); 
    System.out.println("hope you enjoy your visit today!");
    //woop woop it works!!!!!!!!!!
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the rest of your code, and please fix the indentation on the formatting of the code.

Comment: Also, can you define "runs twice"? No line of code in your above example will get executed twice. What behavior or error are you seeing?

Comment: I guess the issue is not the `if` running twice, but you calling `nextInt` twice in the code.

Comment: Just to add, it also doesn't run further than this point in the program if the number entered is 4 or greater.

Comment: here is the whole code.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your program asked for two inputs was because adult1 is the name of your scanner and in your if statement the condition was if the user input is >= 4 then take an Integer input again from the user and multiply that with percentage and store it in adult2, instead this should be done as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

  double adult = 12.50;
  double consession = 9.90;
  double child = 6.25;
  double percentage = 0.80;
  double adult2 = 0.0 // you dont need to redeclare below

  System.out.println("please enter the amount of adults");
  Scanner adult1 = new Scanner (System.in);

    // remove this unneccessary bracket {  
    int num = adult1.nextInt();
    if ( num >= 4)
    {
      adult2 =( num * percentage);
    }
    else
    {
      adult2 = (adult * num);
    }
    System.out.println("Adult2 is " + adult2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the `int` from the scanner and use that value in your `if`s and calculations. You're calling `nextInt()` more than once and each time you get another `int`.

After you enter the if or else you will wait for more input of the integer type stopping the program.